# Android SMS _id

Tags: android, sqlite, sms, android-contentprovider

I googled several times but couldn't find what I was looking for. Android assigns an id to each sms message. I wanted to know if this id is always unique? Can I rely on it to identify sms messages or should I assign my own?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it uses the SQLite, that is a relational database, it's impossible to have a duplicate identifier.

Comment: @Fernando are the thread_id's also unique for each conversation? i.e. does all conversations have a unique id, even after i delete one?

Comment: Uhhh, SQLite doesn't enforce an unique key. Or other constraints. And it's not really a relational database. It's more like a text file with queries.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the source code for [`MmsSmsDatabaseHelper`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.3_r1/com/android/providers/telephony/MmsSmsDatabaseHelper.java) and note the implementation of the `createSmsTables` method:

```
private void createSmsTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // N.B.: Whenever the columns here are changed, the columns in
    // {@ref MmsSmsProvider} must be changed to match.
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE sms (" +
               "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
               "thread_id INTEGER," +
               "address TEXT," +
               "person INTEGER," +
               "date INTEGER," +
               "date_sent INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
               "protocol INTEGER," +
               "read INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
               "status INTEGER DEFAULT -1," + 
               "type INTEGER," +
               "reply_path_present INTEGER," +
               "subject TEXT," +
               "body TEXT," +
               "service_center TEXT," +
               "locked INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
               "error_code INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
               "seen INTEGER DEFAULT 0" +
               ");");

    /* rest of implementation not shown */
}
```

The `_id` that is assigned to each sms message is a `PRIMARY KEY` so yes, it uniquely identifies each sms message.

Answer (score 3):

SMS_ID is always unique for every message.But There is also another column named Thread_ID which is common for every conversation, i.e. very conversation in android phone has given unique Thread_Id.But each message within that particular thread has a unique SMS_ID

Comment: Thanks, nice to know that too :) +1