# Android SMS setting unique ID

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am attempting to develop an Android application that sends and receives SMS messages (among other things)

i wish to have my apps SMS messages easily identifiable.
I didnt want to use the SMS message body for this unique identifier, i thought there must be an SMS message attribute i can use. sadly i have failed to find one or track down a technical spec for SMS messages in general.

does anyone know if the SMS message standards have an ID field that can be se programmatically?

Comment: "Easily identifiable" by who? Timestmap + phone number should make for a pretty unique key, I think.

Comment: "Easily identifiable" by my application. it wasnt the content of the unique id i was interested in, just its location within the sms message format (e.g. sms "header")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.
You can see the contents of an standard SMS message on page two of [this document](http://people.uncw.edu/vetterr/Computer-SMS.pdf), and on [this page](http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/).

Comment: Thanks tanis-7x for your time, i was afraid that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have handled this is by setting an SMS listener with a higher priority than the system SMS listener that looks for a unique string in all received texts.

If the SMS contains the string I handle it in the application and discard the SMS so that I do not litter the users inbox.

The users message alert tone doesn't even go off. It works quite well.

See this post for more info on how to do this:

[Can we delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741628/can-we-delete-an-sms-in-android-before-it-reaches-the-inbox)

Comment: thanks for spending the time to respond, however i didnt want to use the text content itself for the unique id. i imagined the sms standard would make a unique id available

Answer (score 0):

i know it's been 4 years . but in case anyone passes through this question.
yes SMS has unique id called `_id` and you can identify SMS through it.

for more info please refere to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11076049/2968988) answer.